# Disable form control button unless a condition met on sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I searched but all the answers were from 2009-2011 and they are not working the same way as Office 2019.

I have a form and a button which pops up a new Outlook page with attached copy of sheet which contains filled form. I have a cell which contains a formula to check if all fields have been filled and returns TRUE if they are.

I want that form control button to check if F28 cell is "TRUE" and stop working, run to an error or warning message, if it's not.

Comment: I don't have a copy of Office 2019, but surely `If Not TargetRange.Value Then: MsgBox "Fill out ALL the fields": Exit Sub: End If` is fairly universal?

Comment: @Chronocidal thanks for your quick reply. Is that matter if I put it at the end or start of my VBA?

Comment: That depends on whether it needs to do any other calculations before it can determine whether or not to throw the warning:  Ideally, put it at the first point where your code can determine that the fields have not been filled out, so that you don't run unnecessary code

Comment: @Chronocidal I'm not an Excel master so I hope I will make this work)) Thank you very much for the answer :)

Comment: @Chronocidal works like a charm, thank you very much :)

Comment: @Chronocidal can you post that as an answer so we can get OP to mark as answered?  This will help prevent the post from showing up as unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a copy of Office 2019, but am going to assume that the current code is still valid in later version of  VBA

```
If Not TargetRange.Value Then
    MsgBox "Please fill out ALL the fields"
    Exit Sub
End If
```